# which is the best R package for Peaks detections for time series data in R?

Tags: r

I wanted to know which is the best package for Peak detection in R in terms of time complexity,CPU utilization.... I found some packages in R for peaks detection like:

```
PROcess
quantmod
baseline
```

I want to apply the peak detection algorithm for time series data.Can anyone help me out.

Comment: just a heads up, this question will likely get closed in the morning.  You might want to rephrase to something more concrete (as in, "how can I accomplish __ using package X?  This is what I have attempted thus far")    Otherwise, google might be your better option.

Comment: @RicardoSaporta thanks for your response but I have already done with the above packages to detect the Peaks. I just wanted to know which one is the best package for peak detection

Comment: Per Ricardo's comment and your insistence to leave the question as is I voted to close.  It is likely to elicit debate and opinion and not a fit for SO.

Comment: @JackNeil,  how do you define "best"? (This is somewhat rhetorical, please don't answer in the comments). If you have a personal definition of best, then you can perhaps ask a question along the lines of which package measures more strongly on that scale. Otherwise, you're simply in territory that Tyler is referring to.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The robfilter r package was developed to filter time series data to pick out outliers based on robust statistics methods for time series analysis. You can use the adore.filter function to fit a pattern to the data and then pick the outliers that deviate far from the signal.